# Access column in query with special character?

Tags: coldfusion, special-characters

I'm invoking a stored procedure from ColdFusion code that returns a column with the column name "My Column ™".

How can I access this field...? Something like:

```
myQuery["My Column &trade;"]
```

But I can't figure out the correct syntax. Can this be done?

Comment: Do you get an error with that syntax?

Comment: Try to find the ascii code for &trade; and use it instead.  The syntax would be myQuery['My Column' & chr(something)].  A quick search makes me think it might be 8482.  http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm

Comment: I was really curious.  ™  was produced by keying <alt -0154>  However, this page, http://www.cjboco.com/blog.cfm/post/table-of-ascii-characters-and-symbols-for-coldfusion/, says it's 8482.

Comment: The question that begs to be asked is: why the hell is a stored procedure returning a column name with that character in it?

Comment: @DanBracuk - thanks. That worked. I actually had to use it as the itemColumn for a cfchartseries and was able to do `itemColumn="My Column #chr(8482)#"`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
 myQuery["My Column #chr(8482)#"][CurrentRow]
```